# Why can't I Response.Cache.SetLastModified in ASP.NET MVC 2 (and what is a "caching restrictiveness hierarchy" ?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, http-headers, last-modified

Trying to set cache response headers on a dynamically-generated image, I'm getting a weird error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code
>
> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>
> Parameter name: utcDate

I'm reading the file's last write time from a data cache, and then calling

```
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(lastWriteTime.Value.ToUniversalTime());
```

The last write time's value is `{2011-07-25 18:09:56}`, as I'd expect... I have no idea why this is going wrong.

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setlastmodified.aspx) for this method contains the rather cryptic statement (my emphasis):

> The Last-Modified HTTP header time stamps the document with the DateTime value indicating when the document was last modified.
>
> **This method will fail if the caching restrictiveness hierarchy is violated.**
>
> SetLastModified is introduced in the .NET Framework version 3.5. For more information, see .NET Framework Versions and Dependencies.

What is a caching restrictiveness hierarchy? Am I violating one? If not, why is the last modified time being rejected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SetLastModified will throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if your `lastWriteTime` is in the future.

This will succeed:

```
var t1 = DateTime.Now;
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(t1);
```

This will fail:

```
var t2 = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1);
Response.Cache.SetLastModified(t2);
```

Decompiling System.Web illustrates this:

```
public void SetLastModified(DateTime date)
{
  this.UtcSetLastModified(DateTimeUtil.ConvertToUniversalTime(date));
}

private void UtcSetLastModified(DateTime utcDate)
{
  utcDate = new DateTime(utcDate.Ticks - utcDate.Ticks % 10000000L);
  if (utcDate > DateTime.UtcNow)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("utcDate");
  if (this._isLastModifiedSet && !(utcDate > this._utcLastModified))
    return;
  this.Dirtied();
  this._utcLastModified = utcDate;
  this._isLastModifiedSet = true;
}
```

Are you generating the `lastWriteTime` on one server and then reading on another where there is a time discrepancy between the servers?

Some additional points:

- You can also see that you don't need `ToUniversalTime` as the framework does that for you
- Looks like the first line in `UtcSetLastModified` reduces precision
- I can't tell you want a "caching restrictiveness hierarchy" is!

Comment: Finally got the bottom of this... file last modified time was in local time (British Summer Time), which is an hour ahead of UTC, but calling ToUniversalTime on the last file modification wasn't actually affecting it - I'm guessing the timezone information wasn't stored or somehow got lost during serialization/deserialization...

Comment: I see. I probably should have asked where lastWriteTime came from. What's the value of the "Kind" property of lastWriteTime?